# How to run junit tests on a non java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I have a project folder but it is not a java project. It is a maven project. I have written a junit test and it runs perfectly when running in the eclipse IDE but when I run the maven command `mvn install`, it seems to skip my junit tests. I have included the test file in `src/test/java/` (the name of my test is `AppTest.java`) and the main .java file (with the main method) is in `src/main/java/`. I have noticed that the project I am currently working on is a maven project and not a maven java project. I have included a screen of my current folder structure:

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBZKk.png)

[Maven test output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w79KP.png) <- should not build as I have a deliberate test that should fail

This is the POM. I have deleted/commented out some sensitive parts so the pom file may be syntactically wrong but the main plugins I use are there; `tap4j`, `junit` and `surefire`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>integration-api-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>uk.gov.dwp</groupId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>aa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>aa</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.fracpete</groupId>
                <artifactId>latex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <forceBuild>true</forceBuild>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.fracpete</groupId>
                <artifactId>latex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <forceBuild>true</forceBuild>
                </configuration>
            </plugin-->
            <plugin>
                <!-- Plug-in utilised for the execution of the JMeter Integration Tests -->
                <!-- These tests are executed against the nominated integration server where as -->
                <!-- instance of AA exists -->
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <ignoreResultErrors>false</ignoreResultErrors>
                    <suppressJMeterOutput>false</suppressJMeterOutput>
                    <overrideRootLogLevel>INFO</overrideRootLogLevel>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Step to copy the latest plug-ins that form this build to the integration server -->
                <!-- This is done using the SCP command via the ANT plug-in thus allowing it to execute on all platforms -->
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                        <version>0.1.42</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tap4j/tap4j -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.tap4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tap4j</artifactId>
                        <version>4.2.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/cassandra-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/devenv-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/main-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>templating-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipPoms>false</skipPoms>
                    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/latex-templates</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/latex</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin-->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

AppTest:

```
    package AccessGateway;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.tap4j.consumer.TapConsumer;
import org.tap4j.consumer.TapConsumerFactory;
import org.tap4j.model.TestSet;

public class AppTest {

     Practise prac;
     final String DIRECTORY = "C:\\Users\\Hello\\Desktop\\";

     @Test
        public void testHeaderProcessor() {
            prac = new Practise();
            assertFalse(prac.runTest(new File(DIRECTORY+"TAPHeaderProcessor.txt")));
        }

     @Test
        public void testHeaderPortForward() {
            prac = new Practise();
            assertFalse(prac.runTest(new File(DIRECTORY+"TAPHeaderPortForward.txt")));
        }

     @Test
        public void catunittest() {
            prac = new Practise();
            assertFalse(prac.runTest(new File(DIRECTORY+"catunittest.txt")));
        }

     @Test
        public void catunitcrowstest() {
            prac = new Practise();
            assertFalse(prac.runTest(new File(DIRECTORY+"catcrowd.txt")));
        }

     @Test
        public void testCrowd() {
            prac = new Practise();
            assertFalse(
                    prac.runTest(new File(DIRECTORY+"TAPCrowd.txt")));
        }


    @Test
    public void testADFS() {
        prac = new Practise();
        assertFalse(
                prac.runTest(new File(DIRECTORY+"TAPADFSformat.txt")));
    }



}
```

Comment: have you tried to add the java nature? (right click>properties>Project Facets)

Comment: i couldnt find project facets

Comment: please add your pom.xml

Comment: Your test might be skipped if you have the properties `skipTests` or `maven.test.skip` equals to `true` inside your `pom.xml` file. Could you provide us the output of the `mvn test` command ? But only the execution of the surefire plugin that executes the JUnit test

Comment: @MatthieuSaleta I have added the test output of running `mvn clean test` on my post now. I can't upload the whole pom as it does contain sensetive data

Comment: The surefire-plugin is not even executed. It always executes on maven projects unless you configure your pom to no execute it. Do you have any configuration on this plugin inside your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: Please add sufficient information as per [mcve]. Otherwise this will be a very long game of 21 questions.

Comment: @MatthieuSaleta I have added the pom file

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `packaging` of your project which is `pom`

You can't execute Surefire on this kind of project.

Comment: What would you suggest I do in order to run the junit tests?

Comment: If your project contains Java Code, it should be `jar`. `pom` is used for multi-modules project.

Comment: The only piece of java code is the junit tests. Any idea on how I can change it to jar.pom on eclipse if possible?

Comment: Nothing to do in Eclipse. Just change `<packaging>pom</packaging>` by `<packaging>jar</packaging>` inside your `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding surefire plugin. When i have tests in my app i always include it (works for junit as well as testng). Based on your logs i can see that you dont have it declared.

```
<plugins>
[...]
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
```

Comment: I have added that but still same message. I will edit the pom.xml and upload it.

Comment: I have added the pom file to the post.

Comment: looks good.. just remove one of the surefire plugins.. as the last thing.. add your AppTest class here.. with imports.

Comment: Okay i'll delete the last surefire plugin at the end of the pom file. Also, How would I be able to import my AppTest class to my POM file? I'm new to maven

Comment: I mean.. put the content of the AppTest class here.. so that i can see it